# @Autowired not work inside class that class instance create using reflection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection

I am creating spring boot application. In this application there have set of logic class and this logic class instance create using reflection(base on some condition logic is change that's the reason i use to reflection) In side logic class i try to Autowired my repository class but it not work. That logic class annotated using @Component but it not working.

is there have any way to do that. spring use reflection to autowired class therefor  i don't know after using reflection myself, use @Autowired possible or not.

**Code :**

```
interface ILogic{
    void saveUser();
    // set of methods
}

@Repository
interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<ARepository,Integer>{}

@Component
class ALogic implement ILogic{
    private final ARepository aRepository;
    private final BRepository bRepository;
    @Autowired
    public Alogic(ARepository aRepository, BRepository bRepository){
    // code stuff 
    }
    // implementation of methods in ILogic interface
} 

@Component
class BLogic implement ILogic{
    private final ARepository aRepository;
    private final BRepository bRepository;
    @Autowired
    public Alogic(ARepository aRepository, BRepository bRepository){
        // code stuff 
    }
    // implementation of methods in ILogic interface
}  

class CreateConstructor{
    public ILogic getLogicInstance(){
        // give logic class instance base on some condition
    }
}

@Service
class userService{

    CreateConstructor createConstructor= new CreateConstructor();
    public void saveUser(){
        createConstructor.getLogicInstance().saveUser();
    }
}
```

repository class instance are not create inside Logic class.

**EDIT:**

```
public ILogic getLogicInstance(String className) {
    try {
        String packageName = MultiTenantManager.currentTenant.get();//  this return required logic class included  package name. 
        Class<?> constructors = Class.forName("lk.example."+packageName+"."+className);
        return (ILogic) constructors.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch () {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show the code where you create the `ILogic` instance. If you just create it manually via constructor, then Spring won't be able to inject any of its dependencies. You have to request the instance from Spring's bean context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edit the question and add that code.

Comment: `ARepository extend extends`? `implement`? that is not even a compilant code. Please, paste the valid one.

Comment: Andronicus sorry, it's mistake. it should `extends`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring can't inject anything in an instance that you create yourself with `new` or via reflection.

One of the ways to do what you want would be to request the beans from the application context, something along the following lines:

```java
@Autowired 
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void createUser(Class<?> beanClass) {
    ILogic logic = applicationContext.getBean(beanClass);
    logic.saveUser();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and the answer. ( In hear I want to create `ALogic ` class instance this class should annotated as @Component("ALogic")  `beanClass = ALogic` )